# Using global variable as a counter in double for cycle in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, local-variables

I'm trying to use a global variable `x` like a counter in my for-cycles. I'm using the points, which coordinates saved in col_values_X_right and col_values_Y_right variables -- lists of coordinates. I try to use them for creating 15 different plots with them because in each list of coordinates exists separators '-' which indicate the beginning of new data-chapter (which was obtained from another source). It is just an explanation, for what I want to use this code. The problem, as I told before, in that I cannot use my global counter variable in cycles. I try to use `global x`, but I do not really understand how it should work. When I try to run this code it shows me this error `SyntaxError: name 'x' is assigned to before global declaration`. Please, help me, how can I fix it and use x variable amongst all cycles

```
x = 0

for j in range(number_of_separatores//2):
    image_plot1 = plt.imshow(image1)
    global x
    for i in range(len(col_values_X_right)-x):
        if stimulus_name[x+1] == '5_01.jpg' and col_values_X_right[x+1] != '-':
                plt.scatter([col_values_X_right[x+1]], [col_values_Y_right[x+1]])
                x += 1
        else:
            break
plt.show()
```

My additions to the question:

```
x = 0 # the variable, that I want to use as a counter in my cycles 
a = 15
image = mpl.image.imread('file_name.png')
X = list() #put your float numbers here
Y = list() #and here

for j in range(a): #first cycle for making new plots 
    image_plot = plt.imshow(image) #the image on that I want to make my plot
    for i in range(len(X)): #columns of all coordinate that I will separate for differents plots by '-' symbol in it
        if X[x+1] != '-':
            plt.scatter([X[x+1], Y[x+1]) #one point on the plot, the length of X and Y is similar 
            x+=1 #for use next cell of the column on the next iteration of the cycle
        else:
            break #if I find the '-' symbol in column I want to end this plot end start next one. And here is a problem: I want to start from the last x cell, but if I ran this code, after first plot the x value reset and code plotting similar picture 


plt.show()
```

Comment: Why are you using `global`? Your use of `x` is not even in a separate function? It's in the same scope

Comment: @rdas but if I want to count numbers of passed cells in `x`  after `brake` all numbers lost and the process repeats from the start again -- I see similar plots

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with `global`. Something else is the issue.

Comment: @rdas the problem is "how to use global variable `x` like a counter in cycles. So that the data in it is not erased after `brake` command

Comment: You say, "So that the data in it is not erased after brake command". But in Python the `break` command doesn't erase data, so this statement doesn't make sense. This is what's confusing people -- you say you're trying to work around an aspect of the language that does not exist as an aspect of the language. Regardless of what you currently think is wrong with your program, `break` is not erasing data, because `break` doesn't erase data.

Comment: @tom10 But if I use my code, the calculated numbers for one revolution of the cycle in a variable `x` are destroyed after the inner cycle end. I don't know how to formulate it more correctly, sorry for my bad English skills(

Comment: Yes, I believe you that you have a logic error in your code; I just don't think the use of `global` is looking in the right direction. Unfortunately, though, although you've provided enough information to see that `global` *is not* a solution, you haven't provided enough to know what a *is* a solution. Can you post a minimal example, without all your specifics, so that we could actually run the code? With that, I would guess, you'll get an answer in minutes.

Comment: @tom10 I added clarification to the question, please look. Is that what you want?

Comment: That's not really it. I'll stick with what I wrote before: ...*so that we could actually run the code*. I can't run that code you posted.  Now, instead of asking, "what's 5 + 3?", you're asking "I start with one number, add another that's smaller, and don't get the result I want, please tell me what's wrong". Which problem statement is easier to answer?

Comment: @tom10 Oh, okey, you want a full code? But for using it you will need a file with data...

Comment: No, I don't want to the full code. Please don't spend your time on adding the full code.

Comment: I'm basically asking for an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Complete": so we can run the code, and don't need to guess at arrays, etc; but, "Minimal": so we don't need to download data files, or run 100 lines of code. The linked page describes this well. Imagine that you're trying to answer the question.

Comment: @tom10 for now, the last example of code looking like that? You should just put some numbers in lists and use your own picture --- after that it should work, I think

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but this might work. 
Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911821/2071458)

```py
x = 0 #Global

def foo():
    global x
    for j in range(10):
        for i in range(10 - x):
            #Do your own thing here
            if j % 2 == 0:
                x += 1
            else:
                break
    print("Inside: ", x)

def main():
    print("Before", x)
    foo()
    print("After", x)    

main()
```